# git create branch with existing local commits

Tags: git, branch

I have started working on a feature branch and made some changes and commit. But I have not pushed these changes to remote tracking branch. But now I want to create a separate bug fix branch so that I can create pull request.
How can I create a new branch with all commit history i made on current branch without pushing.

I would like to add commit graph for more clarity.
**A**---B---C---D---E---G

So I have made changes on branch where A was already on remote and made local commits  BCDEG. Now I want new branch staring from **A** commit with all the local commit BCDEG so that for review I can create new pull request on existing feature branch commit **A**.

Answer (score 6):

Given that you want to change

```
A` <-- A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- E <-- G
^origin/feature                      ^HEAD, feature
```

to

```
         -- B <-- C <-- D <-- E <-- G
        /                           ^HEAD, bug-fix
A' <-- A
^      ^feature
|
origin/feature
```

First, you need to create your branch

`git branch bug-fix`

This gives you the diagram

```
A' <-- A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- E <-- G
^origin/feature                      ^ feature, bug-fix, HEAD
```

Note that you are still on the `feature` branch, you only need to make the `bug-fix` branch, don't checkout yet.

Next, you need to remove the commits on `feature` (B, C, D, E, G) with `reset` (`A` here is the SHA1 hash of the commit, you can also use relative `HEAD` position):

`git reset --hard A`

**NOTE you will lose any uncommitted work on feature** - please do understand the perils of the `reset` command before executing that command. All the reset does is "push" the pointer of `feature` to the commit A.

Then checkout your new branch and push your feature branch changes for a pull request:

```
git checkout bug-fix
git push
```

This gives you the desired diagram of:

```
         -- B <-- C <-- D <-- E <-- G
        /                           ^ HEAD, bug-fix
A' <-- A
       ^origin/feature, feature
```

Comment: fabulous answer +1, but incomplete. please add the last bit to answer the question where you checkout a new `bugfix` branch from `master` (on commit A). again, good job, I was confused by the question until your answer put it all in perspective for me.

Comment: After reading his question 3 more times, I think commit `A` already exists on a tracked `feature-branch` and he added some bug fix local checkins `BCDEG`. He wants to move `BCDEG` to a local bug (topical) branch so that he can do a pull request of the `feature-branch` at `A`. I'll update my answer to directly answer the question, but the mechanics are the same.

Comment: You're probably right, the question is confusingly worded to me. In any event, I think your answer clearly explains the mechanics. kudos

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already on your feature branch and want to create new branch, starting from feature branch, just do:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch>
```

After that you can push it to origin and create pull request like:

```
git push origin <new_branch>
```

P.S. if I understood your question correctly.